# Variants of the for loop and syntax

Tags: java

so I need some help in understanding this "syntax" or way of writing a for loop

```
for(random : random1) {
```

now is there a way to write this in the "easier" way what I mean is:

```
for(int i=0; random.lenght i++) {
```

I'm interested in how to "rewrite" this in this concrete example

```
public Merchandise findMerchandise(String name) {
    Merchandise found = null;
    for(Merchandise the : merchandise) {
        if(the.getArticle().getName().equals(name)) {
            found = the;
        }
    }
    return found;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think this would be "easier"?

Comment: it's called "for-each"

Comment: Focus on the second answer on the duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/85424/1531124

Comment: Would you consider using a stream as  _easier_?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can write it using a basic for loop:

```
// If it's a List<Merchandise>
for (int i = 0; i < merchandise.size(); ++i) {
  Merchandise the = merchandise.get(i);
  // Rest of loop body.
}
```

or

```
// If it's a Merchandise[]
for (int i = 0; i < merchandise.length; ++i) {
  Merchandise the = merchandise[i];
  // Rest of loop body.
}
```

But this *isn't* easier.

For one thing, it's more verbose: you've got to declare a whole bunch of things (the variable, the size check, the get of the item).

For another, it's more error-prone: you've got to make sure when write all the bits of the loop (the size check, the increment, the get etc) that you reference the right list and right index variable.

For yet another, it's less efficient on lists that don't support random access lookup (for example `LinkedList`).

Want more? You've got to change the code depending on whether it's a `List` or an array, and you can't use it for non-indexable collections e.g. `Set`.

Stick with what you've got.

Comment: how do you know merchandise is a list ;)

Comment: @nafas you're right, I don't. Added both.

Comment: Yea I know that the first way is a lot more useful,but we learned it the other way first,and I just wanted to know how to rewrite it so that I can get a better grasp of the concept. Thanks for the help!